# Is is possible to mark specific methods paterns to return a specific type?

Tags: typescript, class, ecmascript-6, interface

Is is possible in typescript to define an interface that will only be applied to methods that starts with a certain word and cause them to have a certain return type? I thought of something like:

```
interface IPattern {
   [k: 'handle' + string]?: () => SomeClass
}
```

So that a class that implements IPatten and have methods that start with handle would be force to return a SomeClass object, while other methods would not, example:

```
class ForcedClass implements IPattern{
   foo(): number; // ok
   handleFoo(): SomeClass; // ok
   handleBar(): number; // error
}
```

I know a could use an abstract class with all the method that I need, but since the combination of `handle + something` is used in a lot of different implementations, it would be verbose to create an abstract to each of them;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get pretty close with an index signature and template literal types:

```
interface IPattern {
   [k: `handle${string}`]: () => SomeClass
}
class ForcedClass implements IPattern{
   [k: `handle${string}`]: () => SomeClass
   foo(): number { return 0 } // ok
   handleFoo(): SomeClass { return "0 "} ; // ok
   handleBar(): number{ return 0 }  // error
}


new ForcedClass()['handleBaz'](); // this is ok, because of the index signature
new ForcedClass().handleBaz(); // this is ok, because of the index signature
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=77&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYQDYEMDOmoF4qbABOAlgHYDmAsAFDnAREBm6AxtAJIAK6wDRZKAG9aUMQG0A1gC4oAAwAW6MgBNUEACRDCpSgF85AXVkAKAJR4AfLEQoM2Wntqt7OAGJwi7FWiw4SCGDqSGTAONy8-GQiNGJQUrKKymqa2sTkFAbGUOZWNki+DrFiTHBw5rJkAK4IAEaMwlBEEMBVAlAADFB6UAD0vVBwkqJiSqrqHuVmsvAFro3Nre0ARF3LPQDcfQNDI1BjKQBC6EQVUNV1jEJNLW2CXT3bUIxEno60tGQQAO5QHl4QHyucziADkB3UxwAXqDDOYtv0oMAFCR-DghgAaKD1VjoKqYaBwJhIhTQcgqCAADwIJAoZF4bQgnx+f083kKmHMADoIRBofCnsjUVBhZjsRBcfjCcTkWTVFSaXSGc1aEA)

The problem with the index approach, is that while the class members are validated against it, it also means you can index with any value that conforms to the `handle${string}` template literal type, even if the member is not actually part of the class.

The other option would be use a type to validate actual keys of the class without adding the index signature:

```
type IPattern<T> = Record<Extract<keyof T, `handle${string}`>, () => SomeClass> {

class ForcedClass implements IPattern<ForcedClass>{
   foo(): number { return 0 } // ok
   handleFoo(): SomeClass { return "0 "} ; // ok
   handleBar(): number{ return 0 }  // error
}

new ForcedClass().handleBaz(); //error
new ForcedClass().handleFoo(); //ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgYQDYEMDOmoF4qbABOAlgHYDmAsAFCiRQCSACusMBEWQDwAqAfHigAlCAGM4RACbcAogA9i6McG4BrCCDgAzKLwA0UAAYALdGSmoIAEgDehUpQC+R-oYAUASjyD4SNFiYgra0tGIY2FAAYpJiEFIBkSQIYFZIZMA4LGwcXNwxRHEJEUEhNFAV2nBwXgBcUGQArggARpxQtlBEEMCNXFAADFBOUAD0o1BwarQVUGYWVjE1nvV+KCUdXT19ZFAAREN7IwDcYxNTMxXzlhAAQuhEdQ3NbUSd3b39QyNnUJxEkloTlCNDIEAA7tFYvFEpgvAA6a5We4ALy8p3G-0BoIhUMKMJKCKRECW6LOFxoQA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll take an eye on the docs about index signatures, by the way do these implementations also work with inheritance or every sub class must implement the pattern by itself?

Comment: @LeoLetto the sub classes will need to implement this themselves too unfortunately

Comment: Ok, I tried indeed and the first method does with sub classes from an abstract pattern... the second even though it looks more elegant doesn't not work, at this point I'll stay with the first one since I can abstract it to avoid implementing in every subclass